# Find different items between two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, list a and list b. lista has 75060 items and listb has 62116 items.
I am trying to count items that exist in list a but not in list b. I did the following:

```
list_difference = [item for item in lista if item not in listb]
len(list_difference)
```

And the result of list_difference is 2447. I am confused by this number. Wouldn't it be at least 12944 since lista has 12944 more items than listb?

Can anyone give me some insights on this? Is there anything wrong with the list_difference syntax?

Comment: Are those items unique? If not  ten it is possible to have fewer different items than the difference in lengths.

Comment: There are duplicates probably

Comment: What about items that are in `listb`, but not in `lista`?  Like, what if `lista = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` and `listb = [1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: What is `lista` and `listb`?  Where are they coming from?  Do you know what's in each of these ahead of time?

Comment: like a set operation  `set(A) \ (set(A) & set(B))` ?

Comment: You are getting the elements that are in `lista` but not in `listb`.  What exactly is wrong with this result?  Do you actually want the difference between both arrays, like what value(s) exist in _one_ of the lists, but not the other?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the items of `lista` are not unique.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because of duplicates.
Check this example to understand it better:

```
a=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]
b=[1]

>>>print(len(a)-len(b))
12

k=[i for i in a if i not in b]

print(len(k))
1
```

As you can see, result is 1 instead of 12, because of the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the answer you want:

```
x = set(lista).difference(set(listb)) #get elements in lista and not listb
final = []
for i in x:
    final.extend(a.count(i)*[i,]) #get the occurrence of element in lista and not listb and add all to final list
print(len(final))
```